# set CCK field permissions per PHP in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I want to change the field level **permissions** from a *CCK field* by *PHP* in my custom module. Can You give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Implement hook_field_access().

See http://drupalcode.org/project/cck.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/modules/content_permissions/content_permissions.module for an example.